# i have written a list with four arguments.i get a user input for two of the arguments.dont know how to search in the list which have these arguments

Tags: c#

```
public List<train> ViewTrains()
{
    object source1; 
    object destination1;

    Console.WriteLine("enter the source of the train");
    source1= Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("enter the destination of the train");
    destination1 = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

these are the input.
and my list is like this.

```
public void TrainDetails()
{
    ListOfTrainDetails.Add(new train(001, "vivek express", "mangalore", "bhubhaneshwar"));
    ListOfTrainDetails.Add(new train(002, "ganhidham express", "mangalore", "surat"));
    ListOfTrainDetails.Add(new train(003, "mangalore express", "mangalore", "chennai"));
}
```

Comment: You should probably clean up some of your formatting and edit the title to be a little more concise. You can always elaborate in the body of the post. It will make it more readable.

Comment: Also, you source and destination variables probably shouldn't be `object`s. Are they always strings? And your `ViewTrains()` method looks like it just writes output and isn't actually returning a list. Why not make this void? (unless this is part of what you're asking).. It's somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "TrainDetails" is a List

```
Foreach(var train in TrainDetails)
{
     if(string.Compare(source1,train.Source)==0)
         if(string.Compare(destination1,train.Destination)==0)
         {
            //Source and destination matches, do stuff
         }
}
```